# setting a responsive background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar and footer than I grabbed and customized from Bootstrap's site. I now want to have a background imagine, but I'm unsure how to do this. I know if I wanted to have just an imagine, I could put it in a div between the navbar and footer and set play around with `height:100%; width:auto;` so that it resizes with the browser (although this doesn't work perfectly without some modifications) but I don't know how to do this if I have `body { background-image: url('...'); }` I have a large resolution picture in there right now, and on a 1080 screen it doesn't scale down, it just shows 1080px of the original imagine. Is there anything in Bootstrap or CSS tricks I can use? This might be trivial to some but I am new to this, just finished Codecademy courses which introduced me to Bootstrap and now I'm trying some stuff on my own.

So to recap I want to have 16:9 ratio of a large picture, if the browser becomes to narrow, I want the height to stay the same and start "cutting off" the left/right sides of the image so that the center of the image is still in the center of the browser. Likewise for vice versa. the `height:100%; width:auto;` doesn't quite work because if the ratio is wrong, it stretches the image.

I also want to have a different picture if the website is accessed from a screen-reader, but that's a project for another day. Let me know if I need to clarify anything, and thanks in advance

Comment: tl;dr tl;dr tl;dr tl;dr

Answer (score 0):

Use your CSS this way to make the background responsive.

```
body {
  background-image: url("myimage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Then when the page becomes "too narrow" use media queries to switch the background-size properties to actual width and height that work the way you have in mind.